# Is there anyway to generate UI controllers (radio button, input fields, etc) using a loop in java

Tags: java, javafx

I'm a beginner in java. I want to create a javafx form which contains a few input elements such as radio buttons, input types, etc.. created using a loop.

A pseudo code as follows,

```
for (Suit **suit** : suits){
    final TextField **suit** = new TextField();
    lastName.setPromptText("Enter your last name.");
    GridPane.setConstraints(lastName, 0, 1);
    grid.getChildren().add(lastName);
}
```

The problem i came across is how to define the variable name of each element based on elements of the array.

Comment: Please give an example of such an array and how it affects your program. It's not clear how those *"variable names"* are used later in the program. I'm pretty sure we have the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here, so be sure to describe what you're trying to achieve and not only the "variable naming" problem. Also you can't use `**suit**` as identifier and you can't use the same identifier twice.

Comment: for an example an array contains some names of people, I want to create input field list for each and every object in the array. And later I need to getText() from every input field separately.

Comment: It is still unclear to me what you are asking.  Why do you want to "define the variable name of each element based on elements of the array"?  That would be highly unusual.  Rather than using pseudo-code, you might want to create an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your issue (if you do so, make sure it is both minimal, reproduces the issue and is compilable and executable after a copy and paste.  You can edit your question to include such an example.

Comment: I'm struggling to write this code. here is the real issue. I want to write a program which is able to identify the network cards in the the device (like wlan, lan, virtual box...). then after identifying there should be a window to select a network card from a list. the list of network cards in different computers are different. I need to generate a radio button group using the device array. how can i do that? anyway thanx for replying

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is, if the class you want to edit contains javafx properties:

```
public class Person {

    private final StringProperty firstName;
    private final StringProperty familyName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName.get();
    }

    public String getFamilyName() {
        return familyName.get();
    }

    public StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public StringProperty familyNameProperty() {
        return familyName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName.set(firstName);
    }

    public void setFamilyName(String familyName) {
        this.familyName.set(familyName);
    }

    public Person(String firstName, String familyName) {
        this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(firstName);
        this.familyName = new SimpleStringProperty(familyName);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return familyName.get() + ", " + firstName.get();
    }

}
```

You could simply use binding/listeners in this case to bind the properties of the ui to the properties of the person object:

#### Example:

```
Person[] persons = new Person[] {
    new Person("Frank", "Miller"),
    new Person("Jane", "Doe"),
    new Person("Luke", "Skywalker"),
    new Person("Leia", "Organa")
};

Button btn = new Button();
btn.setText("Print");
btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
    System.out.println("-------------------------");
    Arrays.stream(persons).forEach(System.out::println);
});
    
GridPane root = new GridPane();
int row = 0;
for (Person person : persons) {
    row = addPerson(root, row, person);
}
    
GridPane.setConstraints(btn, 0, row);
root.getChildren().add(btn);
```

```
 /**
 * Adds a Person to a GridPane
 * @param pane the pane to add to.
 * @param startRow the first row used by this person
 * @param person the person to add.
 * @return first row below the Nodes added for the person.
 */
static int addPerson(GridPane pane, int startRow, Person person) {
    // use binding
    TextField firstNameText = new TextField();
    firstNameText.textProperty().bindBidirectional(person.firstNameProperty());
    
    // use listeners
    TextField familyNameText = new TextField(person.getFamilyName());
    familyNameText.textProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) -> {
        // you could do e.g. type conversion here
        person.setFamilyName(newValue);
    });
    
    // this is only necessary, if you want to change the family name of a person
    // from the code and the result should be visible in the ui
    person.familyNameProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) -> {
        // you could do e.g. type conversion here
        familyNameText.setText(newValue);
    });
    
    Label firstNameLabel = new Label("First Name");
    GridPane.setConstraints(firstNameLabel, 0, startRow);
    GridPane.setConstraints(firstNameText, 1, startRow);
    
    Label familyNameLabel = new Label("Family Name");
    GridPane.setConstraints(familyNameLabel, 2, startRow);
    GridPane.setConstraints(familyNameText, 3, startRow);
    pane.getChildren().addAll(firstNameLabel, firstNameText, familyNameLabel, familyNameText);
    
    return startRow+1;
}
```

Note that a `GridPane` may not be the best way to add a list of persons to a scene your problem.

See [Oracle Tutorial: *JavaFX: Working with JavaFX UI Components:  13 Table View*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/table-view.htm#CJAGAAEE) for an example using a `TableView`.